# Публикация сайта в интернет без посредничества

Tags: веб-сервер

Можно ли успешно завершить весь процесс от вёрстки сайта до публикации в интернет (т. е. чтобы на него мог зайти любой желающий) используя *только свой компьютер* ничего ни у кого не покупая, не регистрируя ничего ни в каких государственных органах? Другими словами, можно ли опубликовать сайт в интернет, *полностью* исключив *любое* посредничество? Если да, то законно ли это?

Comment: Да, можно. Да, можно. Да, законно.

Comment: Тогда вопрос: чем отличается процесс создания локального сервера с целью протестировать динамические свойства своего сайта (как Вы знаете, для этого нужна дюжина ПО типа Apache, PHP, MySQL и т. д.) от создания локального сервера, с которого осуществляется "вещание" сайта в интернет?

Comment: Ничем не отличается. Только включением/выключением внешних подключения к серверу.

Comment: А доменное имя и DNS сервера? Их-то ведь надо регистрировать?

Comment: @cyadvert Подключение к интернету тоже надо "регистрировать" у провайдера. Статический ip тоже. Так что в каком-то смысле без "любого посредника" никак не обойтись.

Comment: Вот именно! А вопрос звучит: "завершить процесс до публикации .. не покупая, и не регистрируя". Так что не думаю, что "да, можно", это правильный ответ. Как минимум регистрация домена и IP в какой-либо организации все равно понадобится. Некий минимум регyлирования все равно существует.

Comment: очень важным моментом в Вашем вопросе является "не регистрируя ничего ни в каких государственных органах". Ваш провайдер интернета - не государственный орган, а домен можно и не регистрировать, во первых есть dynamic dns, во вторых можно заходить по IP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

0) Вёрстку и разработку сайта можно вести на своём домашнем компьютере совершенно беспроблемно. Можно развернуть *XAMPP*, *Denver* или установить *LAMP* (на голое железо или виртуалку).

1) Для того, чтобы сайт был доступен любому желающему, как минимум необходимо подключение компьютера к сети Интернет. И здесь не обойтись без Интернет-провайдера, с которым нужно заключать договор и, обычно, платить. Можно обойтись без "засвечивания" своих данных, договорившись с соседом (или подключившись без его ведома, но это уже незаконно).

2) Не у всех провайдеров выдаётся "белый", т.е. доступный из Интернета, IP-адрес. А если и выдаётся "белый", то он обычно динамический. Можно воспользоваться сервисом типа DynDNS, но они тоже часто хотят денег, да и доменное имя вряд ли будет таким, какое хочется.

3) Мало кто захочет заходить на сайт по его труднозапоминаемому адресу типа `32.234.54.78`, гораздо легче запомнить адрес вида `www.cool-hacker.com`. Следовательно, нужно регистрировать доменное имя. Это стоит денег и "засвечивания" персональных данных. Можно, правда, в персданных наврать, но если домен угонят, восстановить его Вам вряд ли удастся.

Итак, делаем вывод, что исключить посредничество не удастся в любом случае. Если и удастся обойтись без доменного имени и статического IP, всё равно придётся подключаться к провайдеру и платить ему деньги.

4) А на закуску самое интересное - законность. Читаем Федеральный закон от 27.07.2006 N 149-ФЗ (ред. от 13.07.2015) "Об информации, информационных технологиях и о защите информации":

> Ст. 10.1 п1
>
> 1. Организатором распространения информации в сети "Интернет" является лицо, осуществляющее деятельность по обеспечению функционирования информационных систем и (или) программ для электронных вычислительных машин, которые предназначены и (или) используются для приема, передачи, доставки и (или) обработки электронных сообщений пользователей сети "Интернет".
> 2. Организатор распространения информации в сети "Интернет" обязан в установленном Правительством Российской Федерации "порядке" уведомить федеральный орган исполнительной власти, осуществляющий функции по контролю и надзору в сфере средств массовой информации, массовых коммуникаций, информационных технологий и связи, о начале осуществления деятельности, указанной в "части 1" настоящей статьи.

Первый подход основан на духе закона. Нужно регистрироваться, если Ваш сайт содержит форум, гостевую книгу, чат и т.п., т.е. что-либо, где пользователь может оставить своё сообщение, причём неважно, публикуется оно или доступно только владельцу сайта.

Второй подход основан на букве закона. Запрос страницы пользователем можно считать электронным сообщением пользователя. Ваши статьи на сайте можно считать Вашими электронными сообщениями. Вывод - регистрироваться надо в любом случае.

Третий подход основывается на российских реалиях. Если не будете критиковать власть, а создадите тёплый ламповый сайтик о технике, то государство Вами не заинтересуется и можно ничего не регистрировать.

Comment: Просто нет слов, замечательный конструктивный ответ! Спасибо Вам большое за Ваше время, потраченное на написание этого ответа!